# How to wait for a method to finish before moving on the next line of code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make an Visualization of quick sort using game objects. The problem is, when I put the method inside the quicksort method it doesn't wait for the animation to finish. The code executes all the lines at the same time.

I want to make the method execute first then proceed to the next line. I already tried the IEnumerator function but the sequence is rearranged if I use yield `return StartCoroutine ( myfunction() )`; quick sort is in a recursive sequence. At first the animation works but when the recursion happens, the yield return is not working any more.

Here is my code in C#:

```
IEnumerator swapElement(int e1, int e2)
{
    swap = true;<br>
    go1 = GameObject.Find ("Element" + e1);<br>
    go2 = GameObject.Find ("Element" + e2);

    go1xpos = go1.GetComponent<Transform> ().transform.position.x;
    go2xpos = go2.GetComponent<Transform> ().transform.position.x;
    go1ypos = go1.GetComponent<Transform> ().transform.position.y;

    x1ps = go1xpos;
    x2ps = go2xpos;


    go1.GetComponent<Transform> ().transform.position = new Vector3 (x2ps, go1ypos);
    go2.GetComponent<Transform> ().transform.position = new Vector3 (x1ps, go1ypos);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);

    Debug.Log ("INSIDE SWAP : LEFT : " + e1 + " RIGHT : " + e2);

}
```

Sort Method:

```
int l, r;

int partition(int[] numbers, int left, int right)
{

    int pivot = numbers [ (left + right) / 2];

    while (true) 
    {
        while (numbers [left] < pivot) left++;
        while (numbers [right] > pivot) right--;

        if (left < right) 
        {
            int temp = numbers [right];
            numbers [right] = numbers [left];
            numbers [left] = temp;

            //Debug.Log ("LEFT : " + left + " RIGHT : " + right);

            swapElement (left, right);

        }
        else 
        {
            return right;
        }

    }

}


void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right)
{

    if (left < right) 
    {
        int piv = partition (arr, left, right);

        if (piv > 1) quickSort (arr, left, piv - 1);
        if (piv + 1 < right) quickSort (arr, piv + 1, right);
    }

}
```

I already tried `startcoroutine( swap (left, right) )`, but no luck.

I can put the animation inside the swap method but even then it is still the same: It executes at the same time.

additional information : 
 if I use IEnumerator, the recursion is not working. but if in void, It is working however, the void is not waiting for the animation method to finish. it executes at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the coroutine's IEnumerator all the way up to the top of the callstack.  I would start with turning quicksort() into a coroutine.

```
IEnumerator quickSort(QuickSortArgs args)
{

    if (left < right) 
    {
        int piv = partition (args.arr, args.left, args.right);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (5);
        if (piv > 1) yield return quickSort (args.arr, args.left, piv - 1);
        if (piv + 1 < right) yield return quickSort (args.arr, piv + 1, args.right);

    }

}
```

If you want to wait down in the swaps, you would need to return the IEnumerator from each call in the callstack down to it.

To smoothly animate them, something more like this.   You need to include the time deltatime, and you can use Vector3.Lerp instead of making your own lerp.

```
IEnumerator swapElement(SwapElementArgs args) {

    GameObject go1 = GameObject.Find ("Element" + args.ele1);
    GameObject go2 = GameObject.Find ("Element" + args.ele2);

    float go1_pos = go1.transform.position;
    float go2_pos = go2.transform.position;

    float t = 0f;

    while(t < 1.0f){

        t += Time.deltaTime/args.speed;
        var go1_newpos = Vector3.Lerp(go1_pos, go2_pos, t);
        var go2_newpos = Vector3.Lerp(go2_pos, go1_pos, t);

        go1.transform.position = go1_newpos;
        go2.transform.position = go2.newpos;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1);

    }

}
```

Then you would start this coroutine in the sort method instead of just calling it.

```
StartCoroutine("swapElement", new SwapElementArgs(){ele1=left, ele2=right, speed=1.0f});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply sir. ill try it first. ill send the feed back after.

Comment: they are still moving at the same time sir. ill include my animation code on the question

Comment: What if you move the WaitForSeconds to just after the partition call?   I wouldn't expect it to smoothly animate, but does it at least do the swaps in the expected order?

Comment: sir, ill try this quickly and thank you for your wonderful response to my question. ill update as soon this solution works for me thanks again.

Comment: sir. the position and sort arrange in a strange order. this is what my quick sort code looks like. <br> IEnumerator quickSort(QuickSortArgs args)
    {
  if (args.left < args.right)
        {
   int piv = partition (args.arr, args.left, args.right);

   yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);

   if (piv > 1) yield return  quickSort ( new QuickSortArgs (){ arr = args.arr, left = args.left,  right = piv - 1 } );
   if (piv + 1 < args.right) yield return quickSort ( new QuickSortArgs (){ arr = args.arr, left = piv + 1,  right =   args.right } );

        }

    }

Comment: sir. are you referring the SwapElementArgs as a class so that the values pass can be stored?

Comment: Yes, I'm just in the habit of using the StartCoroutine(string s, object o) signature instead of the StartCoroutine(IEnumerator e)   It should work fine calling it the other way.  For example:  StartCoroutine(SwapElement(left, right, 1.0f));

Comment: thanks for the new technique sir.. :) ill be implementing it on my java codings.. hehehe.. Im using it now on my unity project. the swap element is working right now. but the problem is. the sorting sequence is not in order. so the position of the elements is not in order